# What is the full path to terraform error using bash in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, terraform, git-bash

I am developing a large terraform project in VS Code, and testing terraform in a git bash terminal.

After running `terraform plan`, I often get errors that refer an issue in a file at a line number, for example:

```
Error: Reference to undeclared input variable
│
│   on main.tf line 10, in locals:
│   10:   my_var= var.doesnotexist
```

But it is common to have many main.tf files in multiple modules. So I have to search for the the context base on the error string.

Is there a way to identify the full path in the error message - or better a link to the open file in VS Code?

[CORRECTION] It does provide the path, It's relative to the directory the command is run from, so the above example, main.tf is in the current directory. Other errors are like this:

```
 on ..\..\module_name\main.tf line 108, in module "etc":
```

But it doesn't link back to the editor in VS Code.

Comment: What is the actual code generating the error?

Comment: This example error is that the variable `doesnotexit` isn't declared before its used inside the locals definition at line 10. The problem is which main.tf does it refer to?

Comment: Normally editors with linter packages that output messages like this enable links in the file references for the messages. When the issue is emitted in VSCode can you not click the file name and immediately the relevant file is opened?

Comment: That would be great, but there is no link from the bash shell to the editor.